# Letsencrypt with Phusion Passenger (Nginx) results in aborted SSL handshake

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to get Letsencrypt to work with Phusion Passenger (Nginx) on an Ubuntu 15.10 server.

Steps I've taken:

1. `sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt`
2. `sudo service nginx stop`
3. `cd /opt/letsencrypt`
4. `./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com`

this created cert, chain, fullchain, and privkey pem files.
I then edited my /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.conf with the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen                443     ssl;
  server_name           example.com;
  root  /home/myuser/example/public;
  passenger_enabled     on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
  # File upload size:
  client_max_body_size  7M;

  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    gzip_static on;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
}
```

I then restarted nginx. When I now run `curl -iv https://example.com` I am getting the following response:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://example.com/
*   Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx...
* Connected to example.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

Ports 80 and 443 are open:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Am I doing something incorrectly here? I've basically made my server inaccessible now. Any help much appreciated. I am using Passenger version 5.0.23 if it helps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide has solved all my woes :)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

I've just done this and got it working.

First thing I noticed is that you haven't got

```
ssl on;
```

The other thing I did was followed the instructions at https://adambard.com/blog/using-letsencrypt-with-nginx/

He has far less config than you, e.g.

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;  # was 80, added ssl
    server_name example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
```

...

See if this works for you.

Comment: Which didn't work? ssl on, or starting again using Adam's instructions?

Comment: Adding `ssl on;` to the config I had and restarting nginx :-/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a full guide to setting up Nginx and Letsencrypt: 
[Automating SSL Certificates using Nginx & Letsencrypt - Without the Catch-22](http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/138452017979/automating-ssl-certificates-using-nginx) . It solves the exact issue you mentioned in @Ghoti's reply

Here's the snippet that matters to you. Keep in mind that I used the letsencrypt.sh client rather than the official one, for a number of reasons which I talk about in my post.

---

We’re going to break up the Nginx configuration into 2 separate configuration files, one for the  HTTP server with letsencrypt listening and one for the HTTPS server running the actual web application.

We’ll then place them both in the `sites-available` folder rather than the standard `sites-enabled` folder. By default, any configuration files in the `sites-enabled` folder is automatically parsed by Nginx when it’s restarted, however we want to control this, which we’ll do by creating symlinks.

The HTTP Nginx configuration file will be located at: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/http.example.conf` and look like:

```
# HTTP server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/http.example.com.log;
    location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        default_type "text/plain";
        alias /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

The HTTPS Nginx configuration file will be located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/https.example.conf` and look like:

```
# HTTPS 
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  www.example.com; 
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /srv/letsencrypt/certs/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /srv/letsencrypt/certs/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

    #Include actual web application configuration here.
}
```

### Controlling Nginx

Before we do anything else, we’ll need to first stop the running Nginx service.

```
service nginx stop
```

Then we need to enable the http endpoint by creating a symlink from the `sites-available` file to the `sites-enabled` folder, and starting the Nginx service

```
echo "Enable the http endpoint"
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/http.example.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/http.example.conf

echo "Starting nginx service..."
service nginx start
```

At this point we have a working HTTP server which will correctly serve up any files in the `acme-challenge` folder. Lets generate some certificates.

```
echo "Generate Letsencrypt SSL certificates"
/srv/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.sh --cron
```

After the certificates are generated successfully by Letsencrypt.sh, we’ll have to enable our HTTPS endpoint, which is where all standard traffic is being redirected to.

```
echo "Enable the https endpoint"
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/https.example.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/https.example.conf
```

Finally, we need to tell Nginx to load the HTTPS server configuration, but we want to do it without any downtime. Thankfully the Nginx developers have provided us a way to do that.

```
echo "Reload nginx service..."
service nginx reload
```

Now we have a working HTTPS enabled web application. The only thing left to do is automate the certificate renewal.